# How to get rid of persistent mic buzz?

Tags: microphone, recording, interface

I have a Shure SM57 running into a behringer UMC202HD Audio Interface. It records all sound fine but when i try to record my acoustic guitar, there is a persistant buzz at a G2 in all the track and it always stays in the background, never disappearing. Any tips for getting rid of such a problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wait...so when you use the mic on the guitar you hear a buzz, but not when you mic your voice?

Comment: Is it very close to the strings when you are recording the guitar?

Comment: Is the mains frequency 50Hz where you live? That's near to a G. 60Hz would be slightly flat of B.

Comment: Are you recording the guitar through the SM57 or do you have it connected via pickups to the UMC?

Comment: G2 = 98 Hz, if your mains is 50 Hz, which means the buzz is very near the second harmonic of mains frequency, possible caused by some equipment powersupply.

Comment: @Mark im recording the guitar through the sm57. and the mic is probably around 2 inches or so away from the strings

Comment: @Tetsujin the frequency of mains here is 50Hz yes

Comment: @Tyler Stone yes, i found this weird as well but it might be due to the different rooms i tried these recordings in as one has a few electrical appliances close together - that is one thing ive considered but i need other options because i'll try it tomorrow and if it doesnt work still then something else is the issue.

Comment: @Jackson H Ok, the different rooms is a variable that needs to be eliminated.  Hopefully you are not in one of those vortexes where the laws of physics don't apply.

Comment: Though I do find it somewhat odd that you're experiencing a hum issue with an SM57...with a quality cable, they typically reject noise and hum quite well. I wonder if your environment has some particularly strong interference source and/or you are using a crappy cable.

Comment: Can you post a recording of the sound? I am assuming it's an electrical sound rather than acoustic?

Comment: How far away are you from your computer monitor, or any electric lighting? Both can induce mains hum. Try moving further away.